# SSAS Cubes are using the wrong database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, ssms

I started working on an SSAS solution created by a former employee. First thing I did was rename the existing Database name on the SSAS Server instance. The new name is RMSBak.

In the SSAS Solution I changed a few columns. Deleted some measure/columns. Then deployed and processes the cubes. 
Deployment works. Processing the cubes from visual studio works fine.

We have a SQL Server agent job that fires an SSIS package which in turn processes the cubes. However the job keeps failing. When I look at the report in SSMS, it shows that it is trying to use the database I had renamed.

The error(s) is this:

> Process Cubes:Error: Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error
>   occurred while the 'Basis MTM' attribute of the 'MTM' dimension from
>   the 'RMS Data CubesBak' database was being processed.

I have checked every connection string that I know about. They are all pointed to the correct database. However the job or the SSIS Package or something insists on using the database I had renamed.

Comment: Open up the SSIS package, view the XML code, and do a find for the old database name.  Next, examine the job itself - connection strings can be embedded there directly

Comment: You could also check the SQL Server Agent job, there might be variables stored against it which relate to the DB name.

Comment: Fuzzy recollection here, the SSIS package will retain the cube's internal ID for processing and so it wants to try to process the old one and not the new one. Might also be that you have configurations applied to your connection manager and/or task that are overridding the design time values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@billinkc is right. The DatabaseID is hardcoded at design time if you use an SSAS processing task in SSIS. No change to the connection string will change the database ID it is processing. You have to design the SSAS processing task again.

Or you can backup both databases, delete both databases, then restore them. A restore will fix the DatabaseID to match the database name.

Personally I prefer to use a C# script task in SSIS that runs a few lines of AMO code to process SSAS based upon the connection string (not a hardcoded DatabaseID)

Comment: Actually, I was just able to correct this problem (once I knew what it was - thanks @GregGalloway ) by right-clicking the SSIS Package within SSDT 2012 and choosing 'View Code', then doing a search and replace to replace the old database name with the new database name.